# Spring boot application.yaml variables

Tags: spring-boot

I have a maven spring boot project.

There is something I don't understand with the `application.yaml` file.

What does it means using `${...}` and `@...@` ?

Intellij is doing an auto completion for `${...}` but not for `@...@`

For example I'm using

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health, info
info:
  application:
    v1: @java.vm.name@
    v2: ${project.description}
    description: @project.description@
    jvm:
      name: ${java.vm.name}
      vendor: ${java.vm.vendor}
      info: ${java.vm.info}
      version: ${java.vm.version}
```

And it gives me

```
{
"application": {
    "v1": "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM",
    "v2": "${project.description}",
    "description": "my-app",
        "jvm": {
        "name": "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vendor": "AdoptOpenJDK",
        "info": "mixed mode",
        "version": "11.0.9.1+1"
        }
    }
}
```

Why `@java.vm.name@` and `${java.vm.version}` are both replaced with the right value but `@project.description@` and `${project.description}` are'nt ?

Will there be a difference if I'm running directly inside Intellij or if I'm doing a `mvn clean package` and then run the jar ?

Comment: `@` is interpreted by Maven during the build. `$` by Spring at runtime. I have no earthly idea why you’d want the JVM version the project was built on in the `application.yaml`. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: But here I'm not doing an explicit maven build.  I'm launching the application via Intellij which is doing a build itself.  So why all are not working ?
And for the data pertinence .... well I'm discovering what I can have.  I'd like to know which jdk build the application and which jvm is running the application.

Comment: Do you mean why it's working when launched using Intellij? Because Intellij integrates with Maven, that's why